# Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers, and $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < −1$.

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers. Prove that if $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < −1$.

My attempt:

Trying to prove by contrapositive

Suppose $-1 ≤ a$, we have four possibilities:

1. $a \in (-1,0)$
2. $a \in (0,1)$
3. $a \in(1, \infty+)$
4. $a = ±1$

**Scenario 1.**

Suppose $a \in (-1,0)$. It means that $-1 < a < 0$. $a$ be rewritten as $a = -\frac{q}{x}$ where $x > q$, $x > 0$ and $q>0$

$$\tag1 -1 < -\frac{q}{x} < 0$$
$$\tag2 -\frac{x}{q} < -1 < 0$$

Because $-\frac{x}{q} = \frac{1}{a}$ it follows that $\frac{1}{a} < -1$, and because $-1 < a$ it means that $\frac{1}{a} < a$, which contradicts the fact that $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$. Hence $a \notin (-1,0)$

**Scenario 2.**

Suppose $a \in (0,1)$. It means that $0 < a < 1$. $a$ be rewritten as $a = \frac{q}{x}$ where $x > q$, $x > 0$ and $q>0$.

$$\tag1 0 < \frac{q}{x} < 1 $$
$$\tag2 0 <  1 <  \frac{x}{q}$$

Because $\frac{x}{q} = \frac{1}{a}$, it follows that $\frac{1}{a}$ > 1, and because $a < 1$ , it implies that $\frac{1}{a} > a$. Therefore,  if $a \in (0,1)$ then *it is possible* that  $a < \frac{1}{a}$ and $-1 < a$

**Scenario 3.**

Suppose  $a \in(1, \infty+)$, in other words $a > 1$. Dividing both sides of inequality $a > 1$ by $a$ we get $1 > \frac{1}{a}$. It follows that $a > \frac{1}{a}$  which contradicts the fact that $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$. Hence $a \notin(1, \infty+)$

**Scenario 4.**

Suppose $a = ±1$, then $a \not < \frac{1}{a}$

---

We conclude that the only scenario where when $a > -1$ and $a < \frac{1}{a}$ is possible is when $a \in (0,1)$, or in other words, $0 < a < 1$.

If $0 < a < 1$, then $0 < 1 < \frac{1}{a}$, and since $\frac{1}{a} < b$, it follows that $b > 1$. We know that $b < \frac{1}{b}$, but, as we've shown earlier (scenario 3), if $b > 1$ it is impossible that $b < \frac{1}{b}$. Hence if $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$, then $a \not > -1 $

---

I concede that it must be *very* convoluted approach , as I believe there must be more concise way to prove theorem above. Nevertheless, I would like you to verify whether my proof is correct.

Comment: if you suppose $-1<a$, you should include consideration of the possibility that $a=1,$ and the negation (for the contrapositive) of $a\lt-1$ is $-1\color{red}\le a$

Comment: The last case is not possible, since we have $\frac{1}{a}$

Comment: J.W. Tanner Note the initial statement "Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are **nonzero** real numbers. Prove that if $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < −1$."

Comment: $a<0$ and $a<\dfrac1a$ would imply $a^2>1,$ which is clearly a contradiction if $-1<a<0$ -- no need to introduce $q$ and $x$

Comment: @J.M Tanner I included $ a = ±1$ case.

Comment: @Nelver:  thanks for putting in the $a=\pm1$ case

Answer (score 1):

Considering the inequality $$a<\frac{1}{a}$$
We have only two cases:
1) $a>0$, then we get $a^2-1<0$ and this means $(a-1)(a+1)<0$, from here we get
$$-1<a<1$$

2)$a<0$ then we have $$a^2-1>0$$
And this is for you!